# Accessing values from other tables, Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

In short, let's say I have several models: 
`Driver [id, name]`, 
`Cars [id, car_brand_id, model, driver_id]`, `CarBrands [id, name]`.

So in my `drivers.index` I want to list all the drivers with their cars, of course stating the car brand name. I have also stated all the needed relations within the models.

If I retrieve it like `$drivers = Drivers::with('cars')->get()`, how can I then access the name of its brand in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go deeper and deeper with relations. Eg.:

```
$drivers = Drivers::with(['cars.brand'])->get()
```

Comment: Wow! Awesome! Thank you a lot :)